# Printing a text rectangle

Tags: beginner, c, formatting

I'm starting C as my first language and am just under halfway done the book I'm using. However, I commonly hear about 'bad' programmers and 'bad' code whenever I encounter any sort of programming related discussion on the internet.

I've done some examples that do work as they should but, I want to make sure that when I eventually am able to contribute to projects on GitHub, etc. that I'm not screwing everything up and writing unmaintainable code.

Do these examples follow common best practices? I did have comments but took them out as the code should be easy enough to understand and it's the actual code I'm wondering about.

```
/*make a box*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
    int i = 0;  
    int long length = 0;
    int long width = 0; 
    printf("Enter Box dimensions (LxW):");
    scanf("%ld %ld", &length, &width);
    for(i = 0; i <= width; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    for(i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        printf("\n*");
        for(int a = 0; a <= (width-2); a++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i <= width; i++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Dimensions and looping

It looks like you have some off-by-one errors.  This is not a 1×7 box by any definition that I can think of:

```
Enter Box dimensions (LxW):1 7
********
*      *
*      *
********
```

In C, the idiomatic way to write a loop that does something `n` times is `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { … }`.    (*Sometimes*, the situation calls for `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) { … }` instead, but that's rarer.)  You start your counters at 0, which is good, but you used `<=` in your termination conditions, which is weird.

### Functions

It's a good habit to make a function for any chunk of code that has an identifiable purpose.  Here, it makes sense to define a `void printBox(int length, int width)` function.  If you need to modify the program to take command-line parameters instead of keyboard input, then you can still call the same function.

By the way, `int long` is a bit unconventional.  Unless you have a specific reason to do otherwise, just use `int`.

### Smarter library use

You're basically using `printf()` where the simpler `putchar()` function will do.  The vertical lines, though, can be better written using a smarter call to `printf()`.  (Consult the documentation for `printf()`.)

### Error checking

Functions like `scanf()` can fail due to invalid user input.  You should be in the habit of checking the return value.

### Suggested solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBox(int length, int width) {
    // Top
    if (length >= 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            putchar('*');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    // Sides
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 2; i++)
    {
        printf("*%*s\n", width - 1, "*");
    }

    // Bottom
    if (length >= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            putchar('*');
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{   
    int length, width;
    printf("Enter Box dimensions (LxW):");
    if (2 != scanf("%d %d", &length, &width)) {
        // Indicate input error
        return 1;
    }
    printBox(length, width);
}
```

Comment: Some of that stuff I haven't gotten to yet (ie creating functions) so thanks a lot for this and pointing out stuff like the fact I generally shouldn't use <=. I seem to remember using putchar() once but I see why I should've used that instead.

Comment: @Monado_III `main` is a function. A special one, sure, but a function. So you know at least partially how to make functions.

Answer (score 3):

I was going to write more but [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) already said most of what I was going to say.  So I'll just add this:

## Choice of types

Don't use `int long` or `long int`: just use `long`, which means the same thing.  Also, I'm not sure why you chose to use `long` over `int` here, since I don't think you will want to print a box with a dimension larger then 32K.  Since your dimensions should not be negative, I would either use `unsigned long` or check that the inputs were not negative.

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of @200_success good answer, he still has a bit a code duplication. I suggest the further extraction of:

```
 void print_line(int length) {
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          putchar('*');
      }
 }
```

Comment: width is undeclared

Comment: @Monado_III typo fixed padpadpadpad